# Why is a wrapped COM EXE in C# looking for its configuration file in the Windows SysWOW64\System32 directory?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, com

I have an old Pascal/Delphi application (#1) that is registered with Windows. It is a COM component executable. I also have another old Delphi app (#2) that calls that COM component, having wrapped and declared the types to the component and done all of the magic required to make the calls. It works good. These are all 32bit apps of course.

I have referenced the same COM executable (#1) in a x86 targeted (32 bit) console app by right clicking on the project and adding a COM reference. I selected the COM library from the list of registered COM components within windows (no browsing to the exe of #1).

This added the types and wrapped the COM component and allowed me to call it from my C# console app. However, it fails because the registered COM component is looking for its configuration file in C:\Windows\SysWow64 instead of in the COM component's program files directory (again, the COM component is an executable file for an installed legacy application, #1).

I ran process monitor and watched the other old Delphi app (#2) call the COM component and everything seems to work the same except for when the COM component accesses its config file it looks for it in "c:\program files" where it is installed (install location of #1). When my app calls it the COM component is trying to access the config in c:\windows\syswow64. What is causing the working directory difference in this case?

Comment: "COM component is looking for its configuration file" is specific to how the component is written. At COM level there's no concept of a "configuration file". In fact, at COM level, the COM client doesn't know and shouldn't need to know where the COM server/component actually resides, that's the whole point of registry registration. So you should have a look to how the COM component is written.

Comment: If you have a Delphi client that works fine and a C# client that doesn't, then the most likely the cause is in the COM activation logic, e.g. the parameters of the `CoCreateInstance` method. In addition, the Delphi client may be using some custom activation logic, e.g. running the server manually with the `CreateProcess` method with the working directory set explicitly.

Comment: Is it possible that the current directory is used? What about if you change the current directory to the location of the old COM component.

Comment: The current directory of the process invoking the COM component is certainly not c:\windows\system32(sysWOW64). I thought about what you suggest (changing the working directory) but the old #2 Delphi app is not doing that.

Comment: The old Delphi app is using CoCreateInstance and I have done the same in my C# app--as a test. Same issue. I also noticed that the command line of the COM exe has an -Embedding switch whereas this is not present in the process when run from the Delphi app.

Comment: The `-Embedding` switch should most likely should be taken from the `LocalServer32` registry key, so if you are really are using the same COM object (the same clsid) I would expect that this key to be present in both Delphi & C#. If the clsids are the same, but command line is still different, then I will double the vote on the some additional custom activation logic in the Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Serg alluded to: Windows was starting a new process as a result of the COM call. Turns out that I had to start the process manually before making the COM call. Once I did that, and set the working directory for the process, everything worked as expected. The ShellExecute clue was buried so deep within the Delphi app spaghetti code that I didn't see it until I explicitly went looking for it.

In the end this also required me to perform quite a bit of housekeeping related to detecting, reusing, and killing processes. Multiple processes running would cause issues--as one would expect.